# Angular SSR First Paint appears after styles.css being loaded

Tags: angular, angular7, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I implemented angular universal for my app and served it on a server. But after index.html was loaded browser didn't display any content until styles.css being downloaded. index.html from server contains required HTML and styles.

[image: On screenshot] On the screenshot you can see:

1. time when index.html was downloaded,
2. when styles where downloaded
3. when the first content appears

What can block page content to be displayed, as I expect first content to be displayed after step 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's because styles prevents content from being displayed until it loads